# Qt - Using user text input to direct to folder

Tags: c++, qt, file, input, path

Is there a way to include user text input in a file address? For example:

The user inputs a first and last name, and it is saved as Qstrings `firstname` and `lastname`. I want to then access a folder that is named `firstname_lastname (Ex:`John_Doe`), saved in location like this one:

```
C://Users/User/Documents/Patients/firstname_lastname
```

How would I go about using those strings to direct to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use [arg()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#arg)

```
qDebug() << QString("C:/Users/User/Documents/Patients/%1_%2")
.arg(ui->lineEdit->text())    //firstname
.arg(ui->lineEdit_2->text()); //lastname
```

I don't know what exatly you want, but you can use [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) to open directory. Or you can use [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html)